# Threading in c and initgraph

Tags: c, multithreading, bgi

This is a program I did but the problem I am facing is that its not giving any output. When I try to run one thread its running perfectly else it doesn't. I tried to output it directly in the terminal which is working perfectly but when I try to output in the window using initgraph its not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<graphics.h>

struct myran 
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main() 
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm=VGAMAX;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    const char *message1 = "Thread 1";
    const char *message2 = "Thread 2";
    int  iret1, iret2;
    struct myran a,b,c,d;
    a.x=10;
    a.y=10;
    b.x=20;
    b.y=20;
    /* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */

    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) &a);
    if(iret1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) &b);
    if(iret2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret2);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
    //printf("pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);

    /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
    /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
    /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

    while(!kbhit())
    ;
    closegraph();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} 

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{

    struct myran *ss;
    ss=(struct myran *)ptr;
    int `enter code here`x1,y1,x,y;
    x1=ss->x;
    y1=ss->y;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d \n", x1);
}
```

Comment: I guess, it is `libgraph`. It should be mentioned in the title instead of `initgraph`

Comment: In which case, it's worth asking, is `libgraph` known to be thread-safe? Or do you need to redesign with a single thread that handles `libgraph` interactions, and all the other threads post their messages to a queue or something similar for that thread to pick up?